# How can I set a bit value into a variable and use it as if statement condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query *(trigger)* like this:

```
BEGIN     
    IF (new.edited_id IS NULL) THEN
        IF (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE id = new.author_id AND IFNULL((active & b'1000000' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "you cannot ask anymore";
        ELSEIF (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE id = new.author_id AND IFNULL((active & b'10000000' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "you cannot answer anymore";
        END IF;
    ELSE 
        IF (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE id = new.author_id AND IFNULL((active & b'100000000' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "you cannot edit anymore";
        END IF;
END
```

As you see, the conditions of those inner `IF` statements are almost the same. So how can I improve it?

I mean, making something like these:

```
IF (IFNULL((@variable & b'1000000' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
IF (IFNULL((@variable & b'10000000' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
IF (IFNULL((@variable & b'100000000' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
```

How can I handle that?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to get into the IFs if the 7th, 8th or 9th bit are up, right (different action for each case)? Why isn't the bitwise `AND` that you are showing (i.e. `IF (IFNULL((@variable & b'1000000' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN`) not good enough?

Comment: Yes different action for each case, and now I want to know how can I assign and keep a bit value into a variable?

Comment: The example you presented as "what you want" tells you exactly how: BIT-WISE AND. Check the documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html